# SQL Server - How to Merge 2 different values from 2 Different Tables with same Column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to display only the column where they have different values
Here is the [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c024R.png) I want to accomplish.
I have this code:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerTable c
LEFT JOIN CustomerTableTemp ct ON c.IDCust = ct.IDCust
WHERE   c.IDCustomer =12
```

This code displays all the columns but not the specific column that has different values.

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. Please stop tag spamming by just adding random tags that sound or look familiar to your post. Tags have specific meanings and relevance here. Also, please [edit] your post to include the efforts you've made to solve this yourself. We're not a code or SQL writing service.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. Appreciated. Already edited my post. I added also my code.

Comment: for one customeId, only one column will be different.? or multiple column values will be different.?

Comment: Did the union and the inner joins answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join

```
select customer.CustID 
, customer.Age
, temp.Age
from CustomerTable customer
inner join CustomerTableTemp temp
on customer.CustID = temp.CustID
and customer.Age <> temp.Age
```

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for the help but the column i want to display is random not just the age it can be the Fname or Lname, anywhere in the table. Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible. You can start by editing your question to make it clearer. This answer answers your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Have no access to my console right now to try this out. But have a look for the MYSQL NOT IN() function - or try to use DISTINCT so MySQL removes the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
    Create table #Customer (CustId int, Fname VARCHAR(10),Lname VARCHAR(10),Age Int, Active bit)
    Create table #CustomerTemp (CustId int, Fname VARCHAR(10),Lname VARCHAR(10),Age Int, Active bit)

    insert into #Customer values(12,'first1','last',25,1)
    insert into #CustomerTemp values(12,'first2','last',18,1)

    insert into #Customer values(13,'first13','last1',20,1)
    insert into #CustomerTemp values(13,'first15','last2',20,1)

    SELECT * into #tmpTable From #Customer

    insert into #tmpTable
    Select * from #CustomerTemp


    Create Table #tmp2(CustId int, ColumnName VARCHAR(50),Value1 VARCHAR(10),Value2 VARCHAR(10))


    ;with cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT t.CustId, tpiv.* 
        FROM #tmpTable as t
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            VALUES      
                ('Fname',t.Fname),  
                ('Lname', t.Lname),
                ('Age', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t.Age))

        ) AS tPiv (ColumnName, value)   
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmp2
    SELECT t1.CustId,t1.ColumnName,t1.Value as Value1 ,t2.Value as Value2
    from cte t1
    JOIN cte t2 on t1.CustId=t2.CustId and t1.ColumnName=t2.ColumnName
    LEFT JOIN #tmp2 t3 on t3.CustId=t1.CustId and t3.ColumnName=t1.ColumnName
    WHERE t1.Value<>t2.Value 
    AND t3.CustId IS NULL 

    ;with cte1
    AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By CustId, ColumnName Order by CustId, ColumnName) as [Rank]
        ,* From #tmp2
    )

    DELETE FROM cte1 WHERE [Rank]>1

    select CustId,
      max(case when columnname = 'FName' then Value1 end) Fname,
      max(case when columnname = 'FName' then value2 end) Fname,
      max(case when columnname = 'LName' then value1 end) Lname,
      max(case when columnname = 'LName' then value2 end) Lname,
      max(case when columnname = 'Age' then value1 end) Age,
      max(case when columnname = 'Age' then value2 end) Age,
       max(case when columnname = 'Active' then value1 end) Active,
      max(case when columnname = 'Active' then value2 end) Active 

    from #tmp2
    Group by CustId


    Drop table #Customer
    Drop table #CustomerTemp
    Drop table #tmpTable
    DROP TABLE #tmp2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use union and inner joins to find all the records where the values are different. You can add as many unions as you require.

```
select customer.CustID 
, 'FName' 'field'
, customer.Fname 'current'
, temp.Fname 'temporary'
from CustomerTable customer
inner join CustomerTableTemp temp
on customer.CustID = temp.CustID
and customer.Fname <> temp.Fname    
union
select customer.CustID 
, 'LName' 'field'
, customer.LName 'current'
, temp.LName 'temporary'
from CustomerTable customer
inner join CustomerTableTemp temp
on customer.CustID = temp.CustID
and customer.LName <> temp.LName
union
select customer.CustID 
, 'Age' 'field'
, customer.Age 'current'
, temp.Age 'temporary'
from CustomerTable customer
inner join CustomerTableTemp temp
on customer.CustID = temp.CustID
and customer.Age <> temp.Age
union
select customer.CustID 
, 'Active' 'field'
, customer.Active 'current'
, temp.Active 'temporary'
from CustomerTable customer
inner join CustomerTableTemp temp
on customer.CustID = temp.CustID
and customer.Active <> temp.Active
```